# Page Flipping on Android

Tags: android

I must create an animation when the view flipper is called. I have been looking for a way to create an animation that works with TextView but most of them are presented as images from drawable folder or converted to image.

> Can someone give me tips to create a page flip animation on a
>   textview similar to animation class?

```
    public static Animation inFromRightAnimation() {

        Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
        );
        inFromRight.setDuration(350);
        inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return inFromRight;
        }
```

Calling the ViewFlipper as vf

```
            vf.setInAnimation(AnimationHelper.inFromRightAnimation());
            vf.setOutAnimation(AnimationHelper.outToLeftAnimation());
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you set the ViewFlipper's animations and make the TextViews children of the ViewFlipper, they should use that animation.

Comment: I was just trying to show what I was using. I wanted to create a page flip similar to books flipping without the involvement of an imageview.

Answer (score 1):

I use a separate java file that handles the animation like this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

 public class TransparentPanel extends LinearLayout 
{ 
private Paint   innerPaint, borderPaint ;

public TransparentPanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public TransparentPanel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    innerPaint = new Paint();
    innerPaint.setARGB(225, 75, 75, 75); //gray
    innerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    borderPaint = new Paint();
    borderPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
    borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    borderPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
}

public void setInnerPaint(Paint innerPaint) {
    this.innerPaint = innerPaint;
}

public void setBorderPaint(Paint borderPaint) {
    this.borderPaint = borderPaint;
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    RectF drawRect = new RectF();
    drawRect.set(0,0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());

    canvas.drawRoundRect(drawRect, 5, 5, innerPaint);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(drawRect, 5, 5, borderPaint);

    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

then in your res folder add another one called anim and include this files

popup_hide.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p" android:duration="750"/>
</set>
```

popup_show.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="750"/>
</set>
```

after this is done you add it to your main.xml or the one you are going to use the animation on like this:

```
<com.your.app.name.TransparentPanel
        android:id="@+id/popup_view" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        <LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/popup_textview""/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Periodicos:" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"> </TextView>
        <Button android:id="@+id/hide_text_button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Close" 
                android:background="@drawable/button"/>
                </LinearLayout>
</com.your.app.name.TransparentPanel>
```

and in your main activity.java you call the animation using:

before onCreate

```
private Animation animShow, animHide;
```

after onCreate

```
final TransparentPanel g = (TransparentPanel) findViewById(R.id.popup_view);    
animShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( this, R.anim.popup_show);
animHide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( this, R.anim.popup_hide);

g.startAnimation( animHide ); //to hide
g.setVisibility(View.GONE);

g.startAnimation( animShow );// to show
g.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

long but it works, enjoy.